# An open set in complex plane is the countable union of compact sets and locally compact hausdorff

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, compactness

For part of a problem, I need to show an open set $U \subset \mathbb{C}$ is a $\sigma$-compact locally compact hausdorff space. ($\sigma$-compact is countable union of compact sets)

I suspect its trivial - but I'm having trouble reasoning. Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Local compactness is trivial: for each $w\in U$, consider a closed ball centered at $z$ and contained in $U$. Being Hausdorff is also trivial: each metric space is Hausdorff.

In order to prove that $U$ is $\sigma$-compact, let$$K_n=\left\{z\in U\,\middle|\,\lvert z\rvert\leqslant n\wedge d(z,\delta U)\geqslant\frac1n\right\}.$$Then each $K_n$ is compact and $U=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N}K_n$.

Comment: why is there a closed ball available in $U$ and what is $\wedge$?

Comment: Since $U$ is open, there is a $r>0$ such that $B(z,r)\subset U$. Therefore, the closed ball centered at $z$ with radius $\frac r2$ is also contained in $U$. And $\wedge$ means “and”.

Comment: Does one need to worry that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} d(x, \partial U) = 0$ so that the limiting $K_n$ includes the boundary points of $U$? I think the answer is no because the union does not include this limiting set, only arbitrarily large but finite $n$. Not sure though

Comment: Don't worry about that. The way I defined $K_n$, each $K_n$ is a subset of $U$. Therefore, the union of all $K_n$'s is also a subset of $U$. Since $U$ is open, it contains no point of $\partial U$, and therefore neither does $\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N}K_n$.